# Regular Expression Youtube URL

Tags: regex, youtube

I am using this regular expression to validate youtube urls.

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(?:\S+)?$
```

it works great.

But I have a problem with this.

If user enters http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcKEjSYJVLs&feature=topvideos_sports it works fine

Now I want to avoid this

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcKEjSYJVLs&feature=topvideos_sportshttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcKEjSYJVLs&feature=topvideos_sportshttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcKEjSYJVLs&feature=topvideos_sports
```

same URL pasted multiple times(thrice in our case). For this regular expression it is also a valid youtube address.

I am looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't allow another `?` after the first one:

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$
```

An actual `?` in the query parameters should be escaped, so this approach shouldn't exclude any valid URLs.

Comment: Thanks man! That was really simple... :) I was so mad at it that i couldn't even think of that.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(?!\S+http:\/\/)(?:\S*)$
```

Should do the trick!

Using a negative lookahead before actually matching what is left on the string. :)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(?:(?:\S(?!http))+)?$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vatf)

I changed the last part `(?:\S+)?` to `(?:(?:\S(?!http))+)?` that means, match the next non whitespace character (`\S`) only if its not followed by "http" (`(?!http)`)

Comment: Why not just repeat the youtube bit? Like: `^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(?:(?:\S(?!http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com))+)?$`

Comment: @josh because its so long? No really, there are many combinations that would achieve this, probably it would be good to add `://` to my look ahead. By the way, yours is not working, I put it into the Regexr link and its matching also the repeated address. (Don't know why)

Comment: Oops, I missed a bit there. This makes more sense to me actually: `^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(?:(?:\S(?!.{0,}youtube\.com.{0,}))+)?$`. Guess I'll post as a separate answer.

Comment: Guys,
There is another part to it. Youtube doesn't care about the repeated URLs.. All youtube needs is the 11 digit id of video. Thanks for the answers anyway... :) Having proper validation is always good.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about a double paste then perhaps try this ReGex (base don @stema's answer):

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(?:(?:\S(?!.{0,}youtube\.com‌​.{0,}))+)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails 4 complains about using ^ and $ because of a possible script injection possibility.  Here it is edited to avoid that warning as well as also accept `https`

```
/\Ahttps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=\w+)(?:\S+)?\z/
```

Answer (score 1):

youtube url mostly two type

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcKEjSYJVLs&feature=topvideos_sports

or

https://youtu.be/zcKEjSYJVLs

to validate this in ruby is simple

```
if (youtube_url.include?("youtube.com") || youtube_url.include?("youtu.be"))
   statement
end
```

if you wish to validate by regular expression, Use this

```
/^http[s]*:\/\/[www\.]*youtu[.]{1}*be[.com]{4}*\/[watch\?v=]*([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/
```

thanks